# How to enforce additional include files search order in VC++ project?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

For example I have two **header.h** files located in two different directories **include1** and **include2**.
My source code file uses regular inclusion that doesn't specifies the exact location, like this:

```
#include "header.h"
```

In the project configuration I set my both **include1** and **include2** folders to be in the additional include directories list.

The problem is when I build my project, **include1** folder will be chosen every time, regardless of the order I defined them in the additional include list.

Is there any way to enforce a search order, if I want a specific folder, or specific header file to be used, instead of another, if they both have the same filename?

Comment: This ambiguity is most likely should be solved in other ways. What if you want to use both header in the same project? For example if you would put them into a directory it would solve this problem. So there would be a #include "Folder1\header.h" and the Folder2 version,

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is replacing a header file of existing C project, with a header file of my own, without touching the original files (so no ifdefs in the original header, and no changing of #include directives in the sources). The easy way is not to use the directory with that original header file at all, but it has some other original header files that I don't need to replace.

Comment: There is a project wide setting "C++ directories" that probably is searched before your "additional directories". If you add your `Folder1` first in the main list, it will surely be searched first.

Comment: No, that doesn't works either.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Saying what the header files are would be very helpful if you actually want the problem solved.  Some headers include other headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The include order (as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx) by MS) is:

> The compiler searches for directories in the following order:
>    1. Directories containing the source file.
>    2. Directories specified with the /I option, in the order that CL encounters them.
>    3. Directories specified in the INCLUDE environment variable.

So it really depends on where the include directories are declared. If they're both specified with the /I option (in the GUI under Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories), then the order specified is the order searched. If the directories are in the INCLUDE environment variable (in the GUI under Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories), it depends where they're declared. If it's in the property sheets then you'd have to *not* inherit them and declare them (and other inherited directories) yourself in the desired order.

Comment: I had a similar issue as the OP, two files with the same name in different directories. My problem was that a .props file which includes other .props files had the wrong order. The .props file with the include directory that I wanted, need to be imported last, then it was listed first in the /I option for CL and RC.

Comment: The linked documentation details step 1.  In general, the search is done in the directory of the file with the directive.  That is, if the directive occurs in `DIR\file.c`, the search is done in `DIR`.  In case the `#include "header.h"` directive occurred within another header file `PARENTDIR\PARENTINC.h` that was included by the source code unit `file.c` as `#include "PARENTDIR\PARENTINC.h"`, the directory of that parent include file, `PARENTDIR`, is checked (for `header.h`).  And so on for multiple ancestry in reverse order.

Comment: Unlike MSVC, GCC [does not search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) through directories of nested includes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is going to be difficult to solve.  I suspect that header.h is included from a file in folder include1.

That means that the standard C include path is

1. Directory of the source file (or header file which is including a sub file).
2. Order defined by the command line include.

So to fix this, we would need to be able to stop (somehow) the rule 1 from firing.

The use of `#include "projecta/header.h"` and #include `"projectb/header.h"` are normal methods to achieve this, if you are not concerned with modifying the source.

In your case, you want to ensure your (include2 is included.)

Methods you could apply.

If earlier code (.c/.cpp files) is modifiable, then ensure you `#include "include2/header.h" - which should also set up so all requirements for`include1/header.h` are satisfied.

if `include1/header.h` has an include guard (`#if ! defined( H_HEADER_H)` ) then define this at the command line (`/DH_HEADER_H`), so it is not included - this is a stab in the dark, as the file will not fulfill its purpose.

Write a text modification script (sed?) to modify "header.h" to be "include2/header.h" - which ensures all occurrences in the source choose your version.  That is not too you specification, but could be conceived as leaving the source unchanged, as it would be a pre-compile step.

The goal for guaranteeing the change of order of include may be achieved by creating 2 separate projects - one which uses `include1/header.h` and the original code unchanged.  Then offers out `include2/header.h` as its interface that is modified in some way.